# Difference between map and foreach method in Scala?

Tags: scala

I do have one big doubt when I started programming Scala. I want to know how the `map` method in scala works. Whether it's processing sequentially or in multithreaded? And more importantly I would like to know that why `map` method is faster than `while` or `foreach`?

```
val list = List(1,2,3,45,12)
list.map(x => x)
list.foreach(x => println(x))
```

Comment: How do you know `map` is faster than `foreach`?

Comment: In fact in reality, `foreach` should be faster than `map` because internally `map` builds a `list` in above case where as `foreach` does not build. Any script shows `foreach` to be faster

Comment: Well I tested with code and which results for(i.e. map) expressions are faster in scala compared to foreach or while, etc.

Comment: @Jatin: Do you not think that `println` needs more time to be executed (because it is a syscall) than a simple object creation, which only triggers the GC (if the GC manages a large enough heap).

Answer (score 31):

Firstly, the two operations are infinitely different. `map` is a transformation of the list given a function `A => B`, whereas `foreach` yields `Unit` and is usually used for side-effects.

I would guess that `foreach` is "faster" in terms of cycles needed to execute compared to `map` which creates a new collection (in this case) as the result of the function. But comparing these two is really comparing apples and oranges.

`map` will only be parallel if the collection on which it is invoked is a parallel collection. So in your example:

```
list.map(x => x)
```

is not parallel and is sequential, but

```
list.par.map(x => x)
```

would be parallel. There are obviously various caveats that need to be taken into account with this usage. The same parallel collection has a `foreach` method as well.

Comment: Simple, short and precise. Awesome.. :)

Comment: Nicely explained